# Can't log into Ubuntu, takes me right back to login screen. Also computer runs in abnormally low resolution, possible graphics card issues

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, login-screen

I feel like my problem will be best explained if I just tell you guys what happens.

**The short version: Upon boot, I get the [/dev/sda message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SlDe.jpg), [font changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJjn4.jpg), then [a messed up loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NinFi.jpg), an [orange blinking cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HqmA.jpg), then [the normal login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jQNW.png), but in a smaller-than-normal resolution. Logging in just makes the screen go weird and takes me back to login screen.**

So I'll start from the beginning. When I start my computer it first gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SlDe.jpg), which I assume is normal... (I've never seen anybody else boot Ubuntu and this is my first time using Ubuntu or any Linux distros, so I don't know much.) Sometimes it says something about a recovery journal... But that's all pretty normal. Never been a problem before. But then it changes the font to [this really strange, thin font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJjn4.jpg)(I think it's exactly like the one in tty1-6. It did not start changing the font mid-boot until I installed my graphics card, the Asus GeForce GTX 970 STRIX. More specifically, when I installed the software...).

After That, I get [this messed up loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NinFi.jpg), which I NEVER get normally. It always goes from the /dev/sda thing straight to the login screen. After it's done with the loading screen I see an [orange cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HqmA.jpg) blinking for a brief second and then it takes me to my usual [login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jQNW.png) but in a low resolution.

I can't figure out how to upload a video of what happens, so I'll describe it as best I can. First the login message and the status bar thing on top fades out like normal. A good 5-10 seconds pass before I see that TeamViewer has loaded before anything else. And almost immediately after that, my screen gets glitchy for hardly 1 second total. I see colors and streaks of white rapidly moving across the screen, in a different way and a different speed every time I log in. Then I am taken back to the log in... My only option is to try again.

That's it for everything that happens, but there are a few things that I would like to note.

One, I have a strong feeling that this is happening because the way I installed my graphics card software was very... Well, not the usual way. It kept messing up and not completing the installation due to errors and such, so I found an alternate set of instructions. It involved a lot of stuff I wasn't familiar with, so I didn't understand quite what was going on, but it seemed to be working so I kept inputting the commands it told me and eventually it worked, however I had to delete something that made my motherboard's display stop working. And the other thing I wanted to mention was that the way I had to install the software, I had to tell it to ignore errors or something like that... I don't remember exactly what it was I told it to do, but the point was that it was running into some issues and I told it to just go with it and see what happens. I figured that might cause problems but worse case scenario was that I had to reinstall Ubuntu...

PS: I found out that TTY1(and *only* TTY1) is also orange, like the cursor. Why is that?

Comment: What is your graphics card?

Comment: @CollDue96 [Asus GeForce GTX 970 STRIX](https://www.amazon.com/GeForce-Overclocked-256-bit-DisplayPort-Graphics/dp/B00NJ9BJ8G/182-9529538-0163325?ie=UTF8&tag=pcpapi-20)

Comment: Please show us the link to this instruction set that you followed to install driver software.

Comment: After freshly installing the NVIDIA driver 361 through your tty(make sure you dont have driver conflicts), Go to your BIOS/UEFI settings and turn off the secure boot option. Then try to login.